# Writing "$('#dialog').modal('show');" as plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

The HTML(some view/master page):

```
<div id="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="waitAndLoadTitel" />
```

The point, where I want to put my code is the`_ViewStart.cstml`

```
   <script> 
        $('#dialog').modal('show');
    </script>
```

The problem is at this point jquery is not available yet.

It will be loaded later.

Our aim is to lock the screen, because the css which is rendered at the beginning is  not good looking and will take some time so we will put a layer on top until everything is loaded.

How can I acchive my aim, to show that layer ?

Comment: What makes you think the CSS to show the bootstrap modal is going to load any faster?

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to say , you were just fast :D @james

Comment: @James Thorpe,@Vikrant  Because all the plugin's css(bootstrap3,jquery..) will be loaded earlier and at the end I load the customized css ,where I overwrite these(plugins css) css rules

Comment: looking at this backwards...you don't need script to show that modal if you show it using css and then remove it later with script

Comment: you realize  that bootstrap depends on jquery?

Comment: @madalin ivascu on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ it is written that: "note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the **.cshtml** but you need to wait for **HTML**, **CSS** and **JavaScript** is fully loaded before performing an action using the DOM:

```
<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {
    // your page initialization code here
    // the DOM will be available here

    $('#dialog').modal('show');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you show model in document ready statement

```
 <script>
       $(function(){
        $('#dialog').modal('show');
       });
</script>
```

Comment: actually, which event handler would be the best to load the modal, the document.ready event handler is to late ?!